# YY gets converted to current year

Tags: date, pyspark

I have a dataframe in pyspark and i am having a date filed, some of the data is faulty and i get as 2 digit year, which gets converted to 20YY, for example if input is coming as 19-03-58, it gets converted to 19-03-2058 which is future date, how to i change this into an dataframe to have it as correct format, in this case it should be 19-03-1958. I can check if any date is > current year i can reduce 100 years, but need an efficient way to change in dataframe.

Reduced 100 years if it is future date

Comment: Do you have `yyyy` and `yy` both in dataset. can you give sample dataset and example because i think giving `yy` format to `to_date` converts the date to last year if its in future of current running year.

Comment: Yes getting both data format in the file, yyyy and yy, eg 23/05/56 gets converted to 23/05/2056 and 9/11/1947 remains same.

Comment: IIUC, your date is in string format in dataset and you are planning to convert into date but due to this multi-type data it’s creating issue, right?